# Obter pasta do arquivo com NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá, estou tentando obter a pasta do arquivo, mas sem sucesso.
Já tentei com **path**, com **__dirname**, **process.cwd()**, mas todos retornam o caminho completo, por exemplo:

> C:\node\pasta\onde\esta\o\arquivo.js

O que eu quero saber é a pasta do arquivo:

> o\arquivo.js

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Mas você escolheu a pior como resposta para o seu problema...

Comment: Foi a unica que retornou do jeito que eu queria

Comment: Você testou o `path.basename`? Se sim e não retornou o que você queria a sua pergunta não foi clara.

Comment: testei, retornou o path inteiro

Comment: Não retorna o path inteiro não, você testou errado.

Comment: Na verdade ele trás o arquivo no diretório, eu preciso da pasta e o arquivo, exemplo: foo/bar.html

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92754/discussion-between-douglasteles-and-sorack).

Comment: Então sua pergunta não está clara. `O que eu quero saber é a pasta do arquivo`, a pasta do arquivo é diferente da composição do arquivo. Enfim, na resposta do `basename` tem 3 variáveis diferentes. Apesar de você ter dado uma explicação confusa aquela é a melhor forma usando os recursos do `Node.js`

Comment: Embora minha sugestão funcione, a resposta do Sorack obtém o mesmo resultado de uma forma com mais cara de Node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

não sei se existe uma forma direta de pegar só a pasta do diretório, mas eu sugiro que você pegue o resultado que já tem e faça uma manipulação simples.

```
const caminho = 'C:\\node\\pasta\\onde\\esta\\o\\arquivo.js';

const caminhoPorNivelDeDiretorio = caminho.split('\\');

const diretorio = caminhoPorNivelDeDiretorio.slice(-2).join('\\');
```

Comment: Resolveu em partes, digamos que eu tenho a seguinte estrutura: 

`
/pages/index.html
/pages/top/top.html
/pages/bot/bot.html
`


Na hora do split, ele pega as subpastas certas do pages, mas ele também pega a pasta pages, gerando no output algo assim:
`
/pages/index.html
/top/top.html
/bot/bot.html
`

Comment: Não entendi exatamente a dúvida, qual seria o resultado esperado para essa outra estrutura  ` /pages/index.html /pages/top/top.html /pages/bot/bot.html `?

Answer (score 1):

Use [path.dirname](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_dirname_p)

```
    // filePath deve ser C:\node\pasta\onde\esta\o
    var filePath = require('path').dirname('C:\node\pasta\onde\esta\o\arquivo.js');
    var currentDirectory = filePath.split(path.sep).pop();
```

Comment: Isso retorna igual os outros, eu só quero saber a pasta em que o arquivo está, sem as pastas anteriores e diretório, como esse retorna

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a função [`path.basename`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext):

```
const path = require('path');

// __dirname = C:\desenvolvimento\amostra
// __filename = C:\desenvolvimento\amostra\amostra.js
const diretorio = path.basename(__dirname);
const arquivo = path.basename(__filename);
const composicao = path.join(diretorio, arquivo);

console.log('Diretório:', diretorio); // Diretório: amostra
console.log('Arquivo:', arquivo); // Arquivo: amostra.js
console.log('Diretório + Arquivo:', composicao); // Diretório + Arquivo: amostra\amostra.js
```

---

> [`path.basename`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext)
>
> The [`path.basename()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext) methods returns the last portion of a `path`, similar to the Unix `basename` command. Trailing directory separators are ignored, see [`path.sep`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_sep).

Em tradução livre:

> O método [`path.basename()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext) retorna a última porção de um  `path`, similar ao comando Unix `basename`. Separadores à direita são ignorados, veja [`path.sep`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_sep).